# Workaround for timeout error in Dataset.download()

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

azureml-sdk version: `1.0.85`

Calling below (as given in the Dataset UI), I get this

```
ds_split = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='ret- holdout-split')
ds_split.download(target_path=dir_outputs, overwrite=True)
```

```
UnexpectedError:
{'errorCode': 'Microsoft.DataPrep.ErrorCodes.Unknown', 'message':
    'The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.',
    'errorData': {}}
```

The `FileDataset` 1GB pickled file stored in blob.
[Here's a gist with the full traceback](https://gist.github.com/swanderz/c608ced5f2c6a2802b7553bc9ead0762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried again this AM and it worked. let's file this under "transient error"

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this same issue(timeout error) while loading sqlpool dataset. After spent some amount of time, ***I figured out issue in SQL Query and by optimizing the SQL query*** solved the timeout issue.(It may be useful for someone)

Comment: good to know! when you say "sqlpool" dataset, do you mean a query on an Azure Synapse dedicated pool?

Comment: yes, in sqlpool we are having the data. We retrieving data from sqlpool via Azure ML Studio datasets. whenever we calling the dataset, it running query  in sqlpool and return back the data